# How to load image into Jupyter

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import the necessary packages
from imutils import contours
from skimage import measure
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2
```

```
# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to the image file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I took this code from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/31/detecting-multiple-bright-spots-in-an-image-with-python-and-opencv/

Where do i give the path location in this code

Comment: Are you running this in a Jupyter notebook? Or, are you creating the scripts that comes from that webpage and running it from the command line?

Comment: If you are running it in a Jupyter notebook you don't want to use `argparse` (which is used to parse command line arguments to a script). Where it describes `image = cv2.imread(args["image"])` for line 16 of the code you can just replace `args["image"]` with the path to the `lights_01.png` file that you download.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the stated modules to read the image: cv2, PIL or matplotlib.
Consider reading the following documentation to get acquainted with any of the listed libraries:

- https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html
- https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html
- https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html

Since you are using Jupyter, don't use argparse. Just create a string variable for the path to your image, for example:

`path_to_img = folder/another_folder/your_image.png`

Then just pass this variable to the image reading method, for example:

`img = cv2.imread(path_to_img, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2 as cv

img_path = cv.imread('path_to_the_image')
or 
path_string = 'path_to_the_image'
img = cv.imread(path_string)
```

you dont need the argument parse since you can just pass the image directly to cv2
and if you have the image in your working directory you can do

```
img = cv.imread('name_of_image',0)
```